# Get Table schema using jooq

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, schema, jooq

Currently I am working on a jooq project where I need to perform schema validation of the columns.

Whats the best way to get Table schema using jooq using table name.

DSLContext.meta() is taking so much time to get schema .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

By default, `DSLContext.meta()` queries your entire database with all the schemas and all the tables, even if you only consume parts of it.

You can use [`Meta.filterSchemas()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Meta.html#filterSchemas(java.util.function.Predicate)) (and possibly even [`Meta.filterTables()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Meta.html#filterTables(java.util.function.Predicate))) to filter out content prior to querying it.

Comment: This is taking around 1.5 mins to fetch the table schema. is there any faster way @LukasEder

Comment: @Ramakrishna: You can always revert to JDBC's `DatabaseMetaData` for this, or query the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` (or whatever) directly. I might find an issue in your API usage, but you didn't post any code of what you tried...

Comment: dslContext.meta().getSchemas().stream().filter(schema-> "MY_SCHEMA".equals(schema.getName()).flatMap(schema->schema.getTables().stream().filter(table->"MY_TABLE".equals(table.getName())).collect(toList())



dslContext.meta().filterSchemas(schema->MY_SCHEMA".equals(schema.getName()).filterTables(table->"MY_TABLE".equals(table.getName()).getTables();

Tried both ..First approach is taking 1.5 mins and second one is taking 2 mins

Comment: Have you tried the `Meta.filterSchemas()` method? I.e. call it *before* you do anything else with `Meta`?